# How to match a literal '*' with sed?

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have this line in my file called test.php

```
'dbs_password' => 'a8b*cyP0',
```

and want to replace into:

```
'dbs_password' => 'password-here',
```

So I use this `sed` command with syntax:

```
$ sed -e "s:'dbs_password' => 'a8b*cyP0',:'dbs_password' => 'password-here':" -i test.php
```

However it doesn't change/get replaced.

I would appreciate it if anyone could share some knowledge on the proper way to use `sed` for this such kind of code?

Comment: What do you think the "*" does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `*` in regular expressions means `0 or more of the preceeding character`, it does not mean a literal `*`. In order to match a `*`, you need to [escape](http://linuxg.net/escaping-special-characters-in-linux-and-unix-with-7-practical-examples/) it. For example:

```
sed -i "s:'dbs_password' => 'a8b\*cyP0',:'dbs_password' => 'password-here':" test.php
```

This is needlessly complex however. If you want to replace *all occurrences* of the string `a8b*cyP0` with `password-here`, you can simply do:

```
sed -i "s:a8b\*cyP0:password-here:" test.php
```

If you want to replace *only* those lines that match `dbs_password`, do:

```
sed -i "s:\(.*dbs_password.*\)'a8b\*cyP0':\1'password-here':" test.php
```

That last one makes use of [pattern capturing](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Regular.html#uh-10) to avoid printing the same pattern twice.